# How to Bind TimeZoneInfo in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class that I'm using for a model:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneDefault { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

   [...]
}
```

In the view I have the following code that successfully creates the drop-down list:

```
@model Acme.ApplicationUser
@{
    var timeZoneList = TimeZoneInfo
        .GetSystemTimeZones()
        .Select(t => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = t.DisplayName,
            Value = t.Id,
            Selected = Model != null && t.Id == Model.TimeZoneDefault.Id
        });
}
```

In the form call it with:

```
<table>
  [....]
  <tr>
     <td>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeZoneDefault, "Default Time Zone:")</strong>                  </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeZoneDefault, timeZoneList)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
     </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Everything displays correctly, the issue is back on the controller, I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Profile(ApplicationUser model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.Save();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

The ModelState is invalid when posted back, the error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.TimeZoneInfo' failed because no type
>   converter can convert between these types.

What do I need to do to convert the selected value back to a TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: You might need to write your own custom model binder. I found this from a quick google: http://www.shopmvc.com/news/8/custom-modelbinder-for-a-timezoneinfo-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to use custom binder you can use this trick:

```
// Model
public class test
{
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone 
    { 
        get { return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId); }
        set { TimeZoneId = value.Id; } 
    }
}
```

And in your view bind to `TimeZoneId`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TimeZoneId, timeZoneList)
```